# Webpage breaks due to hr tag for IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6

I have attached two screenshots of a webpage i am designing (I'm new to web-design) as well a dropbox public link to a zip file containing actual page,css and image folder. The problem is that page breaks for IE6 but works as desired for newer versions of most popular browsers. The problem seems to be with hr tag though not sure.

Guys, kindly help me get this correct for IE6 as well.

Your help would save me loads of frustration and time.

Thnks
Romesh.

[image: IE6 View]
[image: FF, Chrome, IE8]

DropBox Public Link:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27899629/page.zip

Comment: why do you even care about ie6? i am quiet sure ie 6 usage is now very low. even if it isn't, its still not worth it (except if of course you have a special case where your users are most likely on ie6)

Comment: @Achshar, if the OP has stated they care about IE6 compatibility **by asking a question that involves it**, there is nothing to be achieved by questioning it.

Comment: alright no probs, just expressing my opinion. sometimes people fail to realize that ie6 usage is actually very low now days and continue to work for it. just wanted to make sure this was not the case here.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not thing that there's a way to fix HR parsing in IE6.

I would switch to DIVs...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `HR`, sometimes I use a `p` element, or `div` element with the appropriate css styling. For instance:

```
div.className, p.className
{
    height:1px;
    padding:10px 0px;
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:90%;   
}
```

Use 100% on width if you want it to extend to the whole width of the parent

Depending on the style you want, try this option and I think it will behave the same independent of the browser.